# Swift Userdefaults converting String to __NSCFString

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, mixpanel, nscfstring

I have code that save a dictionary of `[String: Any]` in  `UserDefaults`. On retrieval `String` are changed to `__NSCFString`. I am using `Mixpanel` to track events and sends this dictionary as events properties. Now the problem is `__NSCFString` is not a valid `MixpanelType` so Mixpanel is discarding my dictionary.

Questions:

- Is there a way to get same datatypes that are saved using dictionary in UserDefaults?
- Is there a way Mixpanel accepts converted datatypes?

Here is a code I am using

```
var mixpanelProperties: [String: Any] {
    get { defaults.dictionary(forKey: "\(#function)") ?? [:] }
    set { defaults.set(newValue, forKey: "\(#function)") }
}

mixpanelProperties = ["a-key": "value for the key"]
let prop = mixpanelProperties
print("Type of: \(String(describing: prop["a-key"]))")
```

asdad

Comment: Did you try to cast the dictionary to [String: Any] when you read it from UserDefaults?

Comment: I think casting won't be necessary here as `UserDefaults.dictionary` return [String: Any]?

Comment: Then I misunderstood, so where does __NSCGString come from then? Maybe you should add some code to clarify your question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have edited my question. Please have a look.

Comment: It is still not clear where __NSCGString comes from, I tried to reproduce in a playground but couldn't do so.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Added code to show usage of the property.

Comment: No this is not reproducible, I get a String back. But to be safe I would read the variable as `let value = prop["a-key"] as? String`

Answer (score 0):

MacOS and iOS use a variety of different classes to represent strings, which are all compatible. x as? String should just work, no matter what the concrete class of x is. Unless you use code that explicitely checks the class which you shouldn't do.